# location permission in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-location

Have have a problem with Android app - On page where need select permission to always accees  to location for normal app functionaly. I try find answer by element, but can't find working answer. In location question who hawe options "Allow only this time", "Allow while usign app" and "Don't use location" if i press "Allow while using this app" or "Allow while using app" we have a app crash (Androis say "App stay sttipoing" and Logcat say error `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field NO_OPTIONS of type Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/Api$ApiOptions$NoOptions; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/Api$ApiOptions; or its superclasses (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api$ApiOptions' appears in /data/app/~~rQbKzCsxKTXKzmSHzMzCww==/com.tost.toster-_CfPHvOMOHPAcSMGw_dcVA==/base.apk)`

```js
2022-02-26 23:47:53.398 10573-10573/com.tost.toster E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: 
main
    Process: com.tost.toster, PID: 10573
    java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field NO_OPTIONS of type 
Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/Api$ApiOptions$NoOptions; in class 
Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/Api$ApiOptions; or its superclasses (declaration of 
'com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api$ApiOptions' appears in 
/data/app/~~rQbKzCsxKTXKzmSHzMzCww==/com.tost.toster-_CfPHvOMOHPAcSMGw_dcVA==/base.apk)
        at com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient.<init> 
   (com.google.android.gms:play-services-location@@18.0.0:1)
        at 
   
 com.tost.toster.firedate.Start.RegisterActivity.LocationRequest(RegisterActivity.java:378)
        at 
com.tost.toster.firedate.Start.RegisterActivity.access$900(RegisterActivity.java:58)
        at 
com.tost.toster.firedate.Start.RegisterActivity$4.onGranted(RegisterActivity.java:310)
        at com.nabinbhandari.android.permissions.Permissions.check(Permissions.java:105)
        at 
 
 
 
 com.tost.toster.firedate.Start.RegisterActivity.LocationPremissionCheck(RegisterActivity.java:307)
        at com.tost.toster.firedate.Start.RegisterActivity.onCreate(RegisterActivity.java:112)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8207)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8191)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3819)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4022)
        at 
android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at 
 
 android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at 
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2336)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8653)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at 
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
2022-02-26 23:52:51.201 10573-13164/com.tost.toster W/alia.cityoflov: Accessing hidden 
method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->close()V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, 
allowed)
```

Here is AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.tost.toster">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

 <application
    android:name=".Main.Application"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/flirt_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/flirt_icon"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Settings.NotificationActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Start.RemindActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Start.StartActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Settings.SupportActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Settings.PasswordActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Settings.EmailActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Settings.AccountActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Settings.ReportActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Profile.ProfileEditActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Main.MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Start.LoginActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Start.RegisterActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Message.MessageActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Profile.ProfileActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" />
    <activity android:name=".Settings.SettingsActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Settings.PrivacyActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Accounts.AccountsActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Premium.PremiumActivity" />

    <service android:name=".Extra.ServiceClass" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="@string/admob_unit_id" />


    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Thank You!